# 9 slice scaling doesnt work for chart fills

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, charts, styling

I wanted to e to replace the standard flex bar chart bars with my own image. This worked by embedding the image and setting as a bitmapfill. however these images dont scale well even tho i have applied 9 slice scaling when embedding.

`[Embed source="bar.png", scaleGridRight="721", scaleGridLeft="15", scaleGridTop="1",
scaleGridBottom="90")]`

`[Bindable]`

`public var bar:Class;`

and when applying

`var x:BitmapFill = new BitmapFill();`

`x.source = bar;`

`series1.setStyle("fill", x);`

The 9 slice scaling options are ignored. I dont know how to resolve this.

One thing to note when applying the same embedded image to a standard image container, it respects the scaling options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scale9Grid` does not work when bitmap is used in `Graphics.beginBitmapFill()` method.

One of solutions is to create a `BitmapFill` subclass that will work with that. [Here is the FXP with solution](http://kachurovskiy.com/f/ria/11/scale9Grid/BitmapFillScaling.fxp) and here is how it works:

```
<s:Application ...>

    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        [Bindable]
        [Embed(source="sample.png", scaleGridTop="30", scaleGridLeft="7", 
            scaleGridRight="384", scaleGridBottom="206")]
        private var sample:Class;

    ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Group left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
        <s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
            <s:fill>
                <local:BitmapFillScale9Grid source="{sample}"/>
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>
    </s:Group>

</s:Application>
```

Solution is based on [bent.googlecode.com](http://bent.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2/trunk/classes/bent/graphics/Bitmap9.as).

Comment: One slight problem i noticed with the code was that it didnt support transparent images. To fix this u can modify line **51** to look like this 
`bitmapData = new BitmapData(displayObject.width, displayObject.height, true, 0x00CCCCCC);`